# Cannot Access Text In A Roblox TextBox

Tags: lua, roblox

Whenever I try to do this set of code in robloxian lua, I can't access the textbox. This code is suppost to do this, but I think that its accessing the property of the text inside the textbox instead. Here is a somewhat representative of the code that I am using. So, lets say that Bob wants to talk to John. I would write it like this.

```
game.StarterGui.ScreenGui.Frame.JohnsSpeech.Text = game.StarterGui.ScreenGui.Frame.JohnsUserSetText.Text
```

Now, JohnsUserSetText is the textbox, and JohnsSpeech is the speech. But when I try to do this, it doesn't work. It just says whatever the text is in the properties. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks! And have a great rest of your day!

Comment: Obviously it will be what's in the properties, *that's* what .Text refers to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much as M. Ziegenhorn is saying, your issue is that you're referring to the StarterGui, not the PlayerGui.

The StarterGui is the container containing the default GUIs to be given out to the player upon spawn, while PlayerGui (game.Players.Ravenshield.PlayerGui, for instance) is where the GUIs are stored for each player.
The PlayerGui can only be accessed through a LocalScript.

The easiest way to access your PlayerGui is obviously to just place the LocalScript inside the ScreenGui you're using.
Otherwise, you can also  access it easily by doing game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui

If I were to put my LocalScript directly in the ScreenGui we're using, it could look like this:

```
local TextBox = script.Parent.TextBox
local SpeechLabel = script.Parent.SpeechLabel

SpeechLabel.Text = TextBox.Text
```

However, you probably want to add text whenever they write it into the TextBox. Then we need to take a look at the documentation for ROBLOX, and specifically the [TextBox Object](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/TextBox).

If you scroll down to the Events, you can take a look at the TextBox.Changed event. This will fire everytime a property of the TextBox changes.
We could also use TextBox.FocusLost, which fires when the client has unfocused the TextBox. The event supplies a boolean 'enterPressed' which tells us whether or not the client pressed enter to lose focus.

```
local TextBox = script.Parent.TextBox
local SpeechLabel = script.Parent.SpeechLabel

TextBox.FocusLost:Connect(function(enterPressed)
  if enterPressed then -- Checking if the enterPressed is true and not nil
    -- The user must have pressed enter to exit the TextBox.
    -- Could mean that they're done writing something.
    SpeechLabel.Text = TextBox.Text
  end
end)
```

All events have to be bound by using the :Connect method. This is what tells ROBLOX to start 'listening' to the event, to make sure the function fires every time this occurs.

Comment: I'm still kind of confused on how to reference it.

Comment: What exactly is confusing you? I can try to explain it better.
The most important thing to understand is the difference between StarterGui and PlayerGui.

StarterGui is the Service which holds all GUI-elements that each player should receive upon spawn. If you make changes to these objects, the players who are currently alive will not see them until they respawn. The contents can be accessed from both script types.

PlayerGui holds all the GUI-elements for each single player. Each player has their own PlayerGui, and displays changes in real time. Can only be accessed by LocalScript

Comment: I'm confused about how I'm going into the PlayerGUI and finding the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

Supposed to do what?
.Text is a property of a textbox or anything similar

NOTE: You are changing a starter gui, which means anyone using that current gui won't get the updated one until they die and respawn. If you want to update the one in their GUI access it through Game.Players.playernamehere.PlayerGui

StarterGui is what the game imports into a player when it reloads everything AKA: respawning or joining

if you need tips on updating each players Gui tell me and I can give some examples

Comment: I mean I want to get the text from the textbox that was inputted.

Comment: then you would want to do what you did but in the player gui not the starter gui  example: 'game.Players.bob.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.Frame.JohnsSpeech.Text = game.Players.john.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.Frame.JohnsUserText'

Comment: its important to manipulate the playergui and not the starter gui as the screen gui is used when the player first joins